# Visual Studio 2008 is not dettecting errors on the fly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

My Visual Studio at work is not detecting errors on the fly... I just can see errors when I build my solution.

Does anyone know how can I configure this? Intellisense is working just fine, but this error detection on the fly isn't.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Service Pack 1 for this, but even then whether errors get detected depends on the type of error: syntax errors are picked up okay, but (e.g.) a class not implementing an interface requires a rebuild.

Comment: For example, if I type: string x = 111; visual studio is not detecting anything. It detects just when I build the solution. And my Visual Studio doesn't have SP1 really. Maybe that's the reason.